# add new instance in a new activity in Moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I'm trying to a create new activity in Moodle it created successfully
but I can't add a new instance in my dB
in my lib.php

```
function activity_add_instance($data){
    global $DB;

    $data->timecreated = time();
    $data->timemodified = time();
    $cmid = $data->coursemodule;

    $data->id = $DB->insert_record('testnew', $data);
     
    $DB->set_field('course_modules', 'instance', $data->id, ['id' => $cmid]);

    // Extra fields required in grade related functions.
    $data->cmid = $data->coursemodule;
    return $data->id;
}
```

no new data is found in table testnew so this error appeared :

```
Error reading from database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the table during the install. Assuming `testnew` is the activity name, the table structures should be in

```
/mod/testnew/db/install.xml
```

You can create the file via Site administration > Development > XMLDB editor

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Activity_modules#install.xml